# How decipher what the terminal Is saying and possibly offer a solution as to how to get the code to work?

Tags: python, terminal

I am brand new to coding on python as well as coding in general. I am doing a project that takes information from google sheets and displays it in the terminal. It doesn't seem to be working but as a beginner (this is my first project), I have no clue what to do. I used google api to get the credentials. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('sheetsproject-765dzxv233334.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('python test').sheet1

options = sheet.get_all_records()
print(options)
```

this is the result in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/jordanmaggin/Desktop/python/sheets.py", line 9, in <module>
    sheet = client.open('python test').sheet1   File "/Users/jordan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
   File "/Users/jordanmaggin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
   File "/Users/jordan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request
    raise APIError(response) gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}
```

here is the tutorial I'm using:
[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM)

Comment: How about adding a scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` like `scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']`? But `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` will be deprecated. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#authorizing_requests) So in this case, how about modifying to `scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']`?

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like it is an authentication issue. you should verify if this user has the right permissions to open this file.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. Could you explain how to verify that the user has the right permissions to open this file.

Comment: The easiest way is to sign in with that user in a browser, and try to open that file in that link. You should see so permission issues.